# 128 bit comparison under AIX (64 bits) for sorting hash values

Tags: c, aix

I need to sort an array of structures like this one under AIX (64 bits) using the xlC_r compiler:

```
struct digest_line {
    uint64_t first;
    uint64_t second;
};
```

Right now I'm doing the long way (comparing the first element, and if they are equal, compare the second element.) Is there a faster way to compare these values?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that I'm using AIX's `qsort()` function. According to `qsort`'s man page, the comparison function is defined like

```
int  (*ComparisonPointer)(const void*, const void*);
```

which (to me) means that I cannot just return a `int64_t` value, but something like this:

```
int compare_digests(const void *a, const void *b)
{
        struct digest_line *aa = (struct digest_line *) a;
        struct digest_line *bb = (struct digest_line *) b;

        int64_t ret = aa->first - bb->first;
        if (!ret) {
                ret = aa->second - bb->second;
        }
        return (ret == 0) ? 0 : (ret > 0) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

This doesn't look... *right*. I keep thinking there must be a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has problems because you're doing signed comparisons on unsigned data.  Use one of these alternatives:

#### More Orthodox

This is measurably faster.

```
int compare_digests(const void *a, const void *b)
{
        const struct digest_line *aa = (const struct digest_line *) a;
        const struct digest_line *bb = (const struct digest_line *) b;

        if (aa->first > bb->first)
            return +1;
        else if (aa->first < bb->first)
            return -1;
        else if (aa->second > bb->second)
            return +1;
        else if (aa->second < bb->second)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
}
```

#### Less Orthodox

This is measurably slower; do not use it.

```
int compare_digests(const void *a, const void *b)
{
        struct digest_line aa = *(struct digest_line *) a;
        struct digest_line bb = *(struct digest_line *) b;

        if (aa.first > bb.first)
            return +1;
        else if (aa.first < bb.first)
            return -1;
        else if (aa.second > bb.second)
            return +1;
        else if (aa.second < bb.second)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
}
```

#### Timing

After doing some measurements, it is clear that the 'less orthodox' method is also slower.  Over 20 runs (each doing 100,000,000 iterations with a different pair of values compared in each iteration), I got the average times and standard deviations (in seconds):

```
            Mean        Standard Deviation
Value       0.732914    0.005000
Pointer     0.655853    0.003895
Null        0.353649    0.003448
```

The difference between the value and pointer versions is significant (0.077s is many times the standard deviation), and the pointer version is faster.  So use the conventional pointer-based version of the comparator.  The 'Null' times use a comparator function that simply returns 0 with no comparisons at all.

Representative output lines:

```
Value:   0.730634 (less =  51517909, more =  48482090, equl =         1)
Pointer: 0.684107 (less =  51517909, more =  48482090, equl =         1)
Null:    0.351807 (less =         0, more =         0, equl = 100000000)
```

#### Test Code

The two comparators were renamed `compare_digests_val()` for comparing values and `compare_digests_ptr()` for comparing pointers.  The Clock type and `clk_*` functions are a high-resolution timer package using `gettimeofday()` on the platform where I tested.  Clearly, there is a considerable overhead in the loop with the increments and accumulating the statistics, but that just means that the difference in the comparators is more significant.

```
static int compare_digests_nul(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return 0;
}

static void time_comparisons(const char *tag, int (*compare)(const void *, const void *))
{
    struct digest_line a = { 0, 0 };
    struct digest_line b = { 0, 0 };
    int less = 0;
    int more = 0;
    int equl = 0;
    Clock clk;
    char buffer[32];
    clk_init(&clk);
    clk_start(&clk);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        int j = (*compare)(&a, &b);
        if (j < 0)
            less++;
        else if (j > 0)
            more++;
        else
            equl++;
        a.first  += 1234567890123ULL;
        a.second += 2345678901234ULL;
        b.first  += 7654321098765ULL;
        b.second += 8765432109876ULL;
    }
    clk_stop(&clk);
    printf("%-8s %s (less = %9d, more = %9d, equl = %9d)\n", tag,
           clk_elapsed_us(&clk, buffer, sizeof(buffer)),
           less, more, equl);
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        time_comparisons("Value:",   compare_digests_val);
        time_comparisons("Pointer:", compare_digests_ptr);
        time_comparisons("Null:",    compare_digests_nul);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating local copies of the structs? Using `const struct digest_line *aa = a;` then `aa->first` seems better.

Comment: At the very least, it is a perfectly valid alternative, and certainly I normally use pointers rather than a local variable.  I'm not sure whether there's a measurable difference in the performance of the two notations with a decent optimizing compiler.

Comment: Yes, I have corrected the signed-unsigned problem in the comparison function. This looks correct, thank you very much for this testing.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best choice on any platform is just to use `memcmp`. This should be highly optimized (and inlined) on any decent architecture. Looking into the assembler should tell you if the compiler is doing some clever optimization. And then benchmarking could tell you which of your versions is best, since e.g alignment problems may also play a role and depend on the type of data you have.

I don't have your architecture at hand, so I quickly checked on my oldish i686 with gcc. The assembler of the following function

```
int compare(struct digest* a, struct digest* b) {
  return memcmp(a, b, sizeof *a);
}
```

looks quite fine an optimized.

**Edit:** Jonathan is correct in his remark that this doesn't necessarily give the numeric ordering of the 128 bit pattern. But as long as you are only interested in a consistent ordering to bring order :) into your digest, this should work ok on all platforms. AFAIR AIX platforms are big endian, so it should in particular work well there.

Comment: The `qsort()` comparison function needs to provide an *ordering*, not just an *"equal or unequal"* result.

Comment: Even without the `!!`, this is going to fail on either little-endian platofrms or on big-endian platforms (I think little-endian, like Intel), so it most certainly is not portable.

Comment: @Jonathan, I don't think that the OP needs a numeric ordering. AFAIKS this is for digests and here usually the only thing you need is something consistent.

Comment: I need consistent sorting so I can perform a diff-like operation between large digest files. memcmp() looks like a valid approach.